# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 - Service start issue

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I recently developed a runnable jar file (JDK 1.8.31).

Then I used [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to convert it into an exe file and at last I used [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) to register the exe as service.

Both the jar and the exe executed well.

I set an administrator mode for the exe file **before** registering it as a service.

Also, in the properties of the service I set the "Log On As" to .\administrator

But, when I tried to start the service from the Services Window I got the following error message:

> "Could not start the --service name-- on Local Computer. The service
>   did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an
>   internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system
>   administrator"

How can I understand what is wrong?

Thank you.